# Vectorization of a while loop including an if condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to vectorize a filtering process in which I used while loop and if condition. To explain it, I make a simple example. Suppose that I have a mathematical function: `f(x) = -x**2+0.25` and I want to generate specific number of points, `num_sample`, between -1 and 1, for which `f(x)>0`. I wrote the following function using a while loop to stop when the number of points is equal to desirable number.

```
import numpy as np    
def f(x):
    return -(x[:,0]**2+x[:,1]**2)+0.25

def generate_x(num_sample):
    xy_array = np.empty((num_sample,2))
    x_tmp = np.empty((1,2))
    counter = 0
    while counter < num_sample:
        x_tmp[:,0] = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(1,))
        x_tmp[:,1] = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(1,))
        if f(x_tmp) > 0.:
            xy_array[counter,:] = x_tmp
            counter += 1
            
    return xy_array
```

I would like to know whether there is a way to vectorize `generate_x` process. Also, I do not want to generate a huge number of points and filter the points that gives the positive f.

Comment: Do you want a list of `np.array` with one value as a result?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: I need a list of x points that all gives f(x)>0. For this simple case, x can be a number or a np.array of size (1,) as x_tmp is. But for my original problem x is a multi-dimensional np.array, therefore x_list is a list of np.array.

Comment: You want to vectorize the construction of a python `list`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Actually not. I just edited that minimal code to be more close to what I actually need.

Comment: The normal numpy way would be to do what you don't want to do.  Question - why don't you want to do that?

Comment: You could create a temporary coordinate array and filter it for valid data points like `x[f(x) > 0]`. That will save you a lot of work in the while loop. Still, you'd have to check whether it creates enough points, and possibly redo that step until you have collected enough valid samples.